# Replacing a substring in certain lines of file A by string in file B

Tags: string, bash, sed, substring

I have 2 files at the moment, file A and file B. Certain lines in file A contain a substring of some line in file B. I would like to replace these substrings with the corresponding string in file B.

Example of file A:

```
@Name_1
foobar
info_for_foobar
evenmoreinfo_for_foobar
@Name_2
foobar2
info_for_foobar2
evenmoreinfo_for_foobar2
```

Example of file B:

```
@Name_1_Date_Place
@Name_2_Date_Place
```

The desired output I would like:

```
@Name_1_Date_Place
foobar
info_for_foobar
evenmoreinfo_for_foobar
@Name_2_Date_Place
foobar2
info_for_foobar2
evenmoreinfo_for_foobar2
```

What I have so far:

I was able to get the order of the names in File B corresponding to those in File A. So I was thinking to use a while loop here which goes through every line of file B, and then finds and replaces the corresponding substring in file A with that line, however I'm not sure how to put this into a bash script.

The code I have so far is, but which is not giving a desired output:

```
grep '@' fileA.txt > fileAname.txt

while read line
do
replace="$(grep '$line' fileB.txt)"
sed -i 's/'"$line"'/'"$replace"'/g' fileA.txt
done < fileAname.txt
```

Anybody has an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any code that you'd like help with, or are you asking for unpaid programming work?

Comment: Apologies, I didn't want for other people to do all the work for me, I've edited my post and included the code I had so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with this script:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {str[i]=$0;i++;next;} $1~"^@" {for (i in str) {if(match(str[i],$1)){print str[i];next;}}} {print $0}' B.txt  A.txt
```

Comment: What's the advantage of a numbered array versus an associative array like the one anubhava used?

Comment: @ghoti None, but for someone who is not use to much to programming or scripting is easier to understand. I think few programming languages accept strings as a vector pointer

Comment: @AwkMan ... hmm, I would counter that you would have a difficult time finding a modern high-level language that does *not* support [associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), assuming it supports arrays in the first place. (bash version 3 might be described as neither modern nor a programming language.) In awk, ALL arrays are associative.

Answer (score 0):

This awk should work for you:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]; next} {for (i in a) if (index(i, $0)) $0=i} 1' fileB fileA

@Name_1_Date_Place
foobar
info_for_foobar
evenmoreinfo_for_foobar
@Name_2_Date_Place
foobar2
info_for_foobar2
evenmoreinfo_for_foobar2
```